# How to make spark commit in each batch when using batchsize and writing into RDBMS (ORACLE, MsSQL, etc,...)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to spark and am attempting to insert 50 million records into RDBMS. The RDBMS can be ORACLE or MsSQL or anything. Below is the sample code

```
df.write
  .format('jdbc')
  .mode('append')
  .option("truncate", false)
  .option("driver", ****)
  .option("url", ****)
  .option("user", ****)
  .option("password", ****)
  .option("dbtable", "TABLE_NAME")
  .option("batchsize", 100000)
  .save();
```

My assumption is that when using the "batchsize" option, it will perform insert in batches of 100k records.

Problem is that it is not committing batch by batch. After a point the tablespace for the uncommitted records becomes full and I get the below error

> ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 6)
> java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-30036: unable to extend segment by
> 8 in undo tablespace '***'

My requirement is to perform insert & commit for every batch based on the "batchsize" value.

Answer (score 3):

"isolationLevel" option did the trick for me.

Reference link - [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.1/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html)

> isolationLevel    - The transaction isolation level, which applies to
> current connection. It can be one of NONE, READ_COMMITTED,
> READ_UNCOMMITTED, REPEATABLE_READ, or SERIALIZABLE, corresponding to
> standard transaction isolation levels defined by JDBC's Connection
> object, with default of READ_UNCOMMITTED. This option applies only to
> writing. Please refer the documentation in java.sql.Connection.

Below is the sample code

```
df.write
  .format('jdbc')
  .mode('append')
  .option("truncate", false)
  .option("driver", ****)
  .option("url", ****)
  .option("user", ****)
  .option("password", ****)
  .option("dbtable", "TABLE_NAME")
  .option("isolationLevel", "NONE")
  .option("batchsize", 100000)
  .save();
```